# updating causes rows in one-to-many table to be duplicated instead of just being updated

Tags: java, openjpa

I'm trying to modify part of a large amount of code written by someone else. I don't know what I'm doing.

I have a one-to-many relation ship: each entry in the code table can have many entries in the code_property table. I have tried to include a minimal example (below), but it is not executable because I don't have the skills to make it so.

My problem is that every time an entry in the code table gets updated, instead of just updating the associated entries in the code_property table, a new set is added instead (even if nothing has changes). There then seems to be some code that cleans this up.

```
mysql> select * from code_property where code_id=341965;
+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+
| id       | name                  | property                            | code_id |
+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+
| 37187304 | incisivRunOptions     | -access +rw                         |  341965 |
| 37187305 | designTabsActiveIndex | 1                                   |  341965 |
| 37187306 | incisivCompileOptions | -timescale 1ns/1ns -sysv -f files.f |  341965 |
| 37187307 | incisivRunOptions     | -access +rw                         |  341965 |
| 37187308 | designTabsActiveIndex | 1                                   |  341965 |
| 37187309 | incisivCompileOptions | -timescale 1ns/1ns -sysv -f files.f |  341965 |
+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have two questions:

1. Can I not expect this to just update the code_property table without creating new entries? (If it were done right.)
2. Is it possible to see what is wrong based on the below code? If so, what?

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "code")
   public class Code extends NamedDatedEntity implements Cloneable {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Min(value = 0)
       @Column(name = "id")
       private long id;

       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
       @JsonIgnore
       private User user;

       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "code", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @MapKey(name = "name")
       private Map<String, CodeProperty> properties;


   @Entity
   @Table(name = "code_property")
   public class CodeProperty extends Property implements Cloneable{

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Min(value = 0)
       @Column(name = "id")
       private long id;

       @ManyToOne
       @JsonIgnore
       private Code code;
   ```

Comment: 1) yes 2) it depends - you should rather show the codefragment, where the entities are updated

Comment: @GyroGearless 1) Thank you. 2) Trying to create some get of minimal way of posting that code fragment has given me something else to think about / try. (Such is the beauty of a [mcve].) I'll be back...